# How to do Fixed length subnetting?

Tags: subnet, ipv4

This was an exam question last year, and I was trying to figure out how to get the answer:

A small company is assigned the class C network 205.67.35.0. You need to divide this network to provide subnets for three departments using fixed-length subnetting. The departments are approximately the same size. Show the network and broadcast addresses for each subnet. Show the slash notation. How many hosts are on each subnet? Are the resulting subnets class C networks?

How would you go about doing this? How would you start it?

Answer (score 0):

There are 256 addresses in the given network. That means your subnets can have 64 addresses each, i.e. they are /26 subnets. Everything else follows by simple calculation.